# Update validation for SXA items

Tags: sxa, validation

I am using Sitecore with SXA and I want to add validation for the SXA promo item. I need to know the best way to do this.

For more clarification, I want to add required field validation on the "PromoText" field in this template "`/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Page Content/Promo/Promo`" and this template is a template that is added by SXA:

[image]

Should I add the validation on the field of the SXA item template and use TDS field level deployment OR should I clone the template to do my updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never alter the ootb SXA templates - if you want to make a change like adding validation you should create your on copy. So clone the template, make your changes and clone the component to use your templates.

Cloning the rendering gives you the flexibility you need to change anything you want (even if it is only adding validation) but it also keeps you safe when doing an upgrade.